# Google map markers are not displaying with ajax json data

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am getting `latitude` & `longitude` from database table and trying to display markers on `ajax success`. I am getting `latitude` & `longitude` on json format but when tried with loop, markers are not displaying.

My JSON Data:

```
[
    {"latitude":"23.046100780353495","longitude":"72.56860542227514"},
    {"latitude":"23.088427701737665","longitude":"72.49273109366186"},
    {"latitude":"23.061264193197644","longitude":"72.68224525381811"},
    {"latitude":"22.977212139977677","longitude":"72.52191352774389"},
    {"latitude":"23.002180435752084","longitude":"72.47590827872045"},
    {"latitude":"23.108638843843046","longitude":"72.49444770743139"}
]
```

Google map with Ajax Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Check DOM Ready
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Execute
    (function() {
        // Map options
        var options = {
            zoom: 6,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(23.039567700000000000, 72.566004499999960000), // Centered
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
            mapTypeControl: false
        };

        // Init map
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), options);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'get-locations.php',
            success:function(data){
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                var totalLocations = obj.length;

                for (var i = 0; i < totalLocations; i++) {

                    // Init markers
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(obj[i].latitude + ',' + obj[i].longitude),
                        map: map,
                        title: 'Click Me ' + i
                    });

                    // Process multiple info windows
                    (function(marker, i) {
                        // add click event
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                content: 'Hello, World!!'
                            });
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        });
                    })(marker, i);

                }

            }
        });
    })();
});
</script>
```

When I tried to pass static `latitude` & `longitude` inside the loop marker is displayed:

```
position: new google.maps.LatLng(23.046100780353495,72.56860542227514),
```

but not working with dynamic with loop.

Any idea why markers are not displaying?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing the coordinates incorrectly to the [`google.maps.LatLng`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) constructor. There should be two parameters separated by a comma but you're concatenating them as a string.

The code should look like this:

```
position: new google.maps.LatLng(obj[i].latitude, obj[i].longitude)
```